# conditionally change widget type in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-widget

I have the following simple form:

```
class ContactEmailForm(forms.ModelForm):

    subject = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SUBJECT_TYPES)

    class Meta:
        model = ContactEmail
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message',)
```

I want to conditionally change the subject field between a choice field and text input field.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished by overriding the `__init__` function within your ContactEmailForm class.

```
class ContactEmailForm(forms.ModelForm):

    subject = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SUBJECT_TYPES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactEmailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if YOURCONDITION:
            self.fields['subject'] = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = ContactEmail
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'subject', 'message',)
```

Comment: It is also possible to use the instance of the model as `self.instance` in the condition.